# MSP432p401r: What are the possible inputs to CTLW0->BRW?

Tags: msp430, code-composer, msp432

The project I am working on includes i2c. I am looking through the datasheets and I cannot find how to use the prescaler setting, BRW. The section on this register does not tell me anything. It is [here](http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/slau356h/slau356h.pdf) on the top of page 982. How does this register affect the SCL frequency?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Section 26.3.6 of the linked manual says:

> The 16-bit value of UCBRx in register UCBxBRW is the division factor of the eUSCI_B clock source, BRCLK. […] The BITCLK frequency is given by:
>
> f<sub>BitClock</sub> = f<sub>BRCLK</sub>/UCBRx
>
> The minimum high and low periods of the generated SCL are:
>
> t<sub>LOW,MIN</sub> = t<sub>HIGH,MIN</sub> = (UCBRx/2)/f<sub>BRCLK</sub> when UCBRx is even
>
> t<sub>LOW,MIN</sub> = t<sub>HIGH,MIN</sub> = ((UCBRx – 1)/2)/f<sub>BRCLK</sub> when UCBRx is odd